# I am trying to fetch messages from my phone in my app, but some of them don't show up

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, telephony

Half of the messages are not showing up, even on my phone I can see the messages in Truecaller but not in Google messages, I have tried changing my default sms app but nothing seems to work.

```
final telephony = Telephony.instance;
List\<SmsMessage\> messages = await telephony.getInboxSms(
columns: \[SmsColumn.ADDRESS, SmsColumn.BODY, SmsColumn.DATE\],
filter: SmsFilter.where(SmsColumn.BODY).like('%A/c \*2224%'),
sortOrder: \[
OrderBy(SmsColumn.DATE, sort: Sort.DESC),
OrderBy(SmsColumn.BODY)
\]);
```